# System.setProperty in java

Tags: java

Is using System.setProperty equivalent to passing the variables in commandline argument in java?

eg:
Can this

```
java -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=trustore.jks
```

be replaced by removing -D from the above and adding below in the code

`System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "truststore.jks")`

Comment: Yes, they are equivalent, but their timing is not.  The command-line form guarantees the property is set before the Java runtime starts.  Setting a property in code may be too late, as some system functionality which makes use of that property may already be initialized when your code executes.

Comment: This comment should be an answer, IMHO

Comment: What is the best alternative for command line args then?

Comment: I’m not sure there is one.  Most applications that need to set up system properties have their own startup scripts that add `-D` options to the command line.